# Android emulator is not starting for hello word

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, adt

I'm just starting to learn android programming.
I downloaded the ADT and went through the manual for the hello world! project.
But when I want to run my project I see this in console:

```
[2013-01-12 19:34:20 - HelloWorld] ------------------------------
[2013-01-12 19:34:20 - HelloWorld] Android Launch!
[2013-01-12 19:34:20 - HelloWorld] adb is running normally.
[2013-01-12 19:34:20 - HelloWorld] Performing com.example.helloworld.MainActivity activity     launch
[2013-01-12 19:34:20 - HelloWorld] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'Nexus7' is not     available. Launching new emulator.
[2013-01-12 19:34:20 - HelloWorld] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Nexus7'
[2013-01-12 19:34:20 - Emulator] emulator: ERROR: No initial system image for this configuration!
```

I'm using MAC OSX

Tell me if more information is needed!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you created an Android x86 AVD when setting the emulator type up?

Comment: Have installed the requisite AVD and made an emulator for that using the AVD manager?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I just went to AVD manager and then created a new AVD by nexus7 setting. should I do any thing else?

Answer (score 0):

Among the SDKs installed, your PC seems to be missing the system image required for the AVD to start.

Go to the SDK manager and check if the components have been downloaded properly or not.

For further details, check [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40824).

Comment: I've got "SDK platform Android 4.2" and "ARM EABI v7a System image" here.

Comment: And is your AVD created properly ?