# emulator: ERROR: No initial system image for this configuration

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

During launching the AVD, I am getting error as "**emulator: ERROR: No initial system image for this configuration!**". I have downloaded the sdk ADT bundle for window from **http://developer.android.com/sdk/index**. Please help in removing the error.

Comment: have you downloaded the system image from sdk

Comment: downloading again the image file as it seems corrupted during unzipping the sdk bundle. Thanks for your quick reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the SDK manager and check if the components have been downloaded properly or not.

For further details, check [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40824).

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295572/android-emulator-is-not-starting-for-hello-word).

Comment: It seems that image file inside sdk bundle got corrupted during extracting as i had got some error during extraction. Thanks. The link provided by you "https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40824" was really helpful.

Comment: I was missing other dependencies, this command helped me,
sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential \ zip curl zlib1g-dev gcc-multilib g++-multilib libc6-dev-i386 \ lib32ncurses5-dev x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev lib32z-dev ccache \ libgl1-mesa-dev libxml2-utils xsltproc unzip

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the system image files and re-installing them from the sdk manager worked out for me.